# app crash on iOS Swift insert rows at index path with animation

Tags: ios, swift

I have a table view controller with static cells in 5 sections. I would like to add a second row to one of the sections when a UISegmentedControl object in the first row of that section is tapped (value change action function). I do not have a data source for this as I only intend to use the new row to display a text field. At this time I am only looking to see an empty row appear with animation, so that I may add the text field programmatically later on.The iOS simulator crashes whenever I tap the segmented control. No error message. Xcode 7 iOS 9. I've looked up other responses to similar queries but unable to identify the issue. Any help appreciated. My code is below. Thanks!

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

// init with 1 row in section 3 of table view. This row contains the segment 
// control object

 var rowsInMySection = 1

// index path for new row (second row) to be added to section 3 

var indexPath1 = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 3)

 override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 5
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    var rows = 1

    if section == 3 {
    rows = rowsInMySection

    }

    else {
    rows = 1
    }

    return rows
    }

 @IBAction func segmentControlTapped(sender: UISegmentedControl) {


 if(segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)

 {

         self.tableView.beginUpdates()
         self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath1],
            withRowAnimation : UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
         self.rowsInMySection = 2

        self.tableView.endUpdates()

    }


   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question. You have a static `tableView` so by definition it can't be added to or removed from.

Comment: Thanks pbush25.  I'm new to iOS, I wasn't aware that static table views do not permit programmatic addition of static rows. I'll see if this works with dynamic cells.